# Where to define data contracts in C

Tags: c

I am working on a C project where I will be creating a dynamically linked library and using that in an executable. The dll code functions will return various data structs. Where is the best place to define those? Common header files that will be used by dll and executable? What are the general practices?

Comment: If something (struct, function, etc) will be used by external code (as yours will be), put it in the header file. If it will not be used by external code, try to refrain from doing so (although sometimes you have to if your DLL is split into multiple files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean define or declare? You should declare them in a header file which also contains the signatures of the functions of your library. The calling code defines them (allocates memory for it). Generally I would recommend you to use dynamic memory for your structs except the structs are really small.

Basically there are two possible ways to implement this:

1. Define a pointer to the data struct in the calling code, allocate memory on heap for this struct and pass this pointer into the functions of your library that work with it (and that return it afterwards)
2. Define a pointer to the data struct in the calling code and pass a pointer to this pointer to the function. The library function allocates memory for the struct in the function body, works with the structure, for example filling it with data, and returns it after that.

In both cases you have to free the data structs after using them. I often provide a library function to free data structs, especially when I'm using structs containing poitners to other structs in it.